# How to use more than one filter in my function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

A colleague made a filter function to filter through cups of coffee.
It filters through 3 kinds of things. intensity, cupsize and moment of the day.

For now I can only make one of the three work at the time. I can't seem to find out how I can make them all work.

This is the code that makes one of them work:

```
EventBus.$on('set-filter', (cupFilters) => {
  if (!cupFilters.intensities.length) {
    this.filteredOut = false;
    return;
  }
  this.filteredOut = !cupFilters.intensities.includes(this.cup.intensity);
});
```

I tried adding the moment filter like this:

```
EventBus.$on('set-filter', (cupFilters) => {
  if (!cupFilters.intensities.length || !cupFilters.moments.length) {
    this.filteredOut = false;
    return;
  }
  this.filteredOut = !cupFilters.intensities.includes(this.cup.intensity);
  this.filteredOut = !cupFilters.moments.includes(this.cup. coffee_moment_id);
});
```

But then it just take the last one and only that one works.

Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.
I can provide the filter code itself also if needed, but that seems to work fine by itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. not sure about the logic though (only take the syntax change)

```
this.filteredOut =  (!cupFilters.intensities.length || !cupFilters.moments.length) 
    ? false
    : (!cupFilters.intensities.includes(this.cup.intensity) || !cupFilters.moments.includes(this.cup. coffee_moment_id)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not taking into account any of your previous results. The boolean operations help here.

Let's start with what you're currently doing:

```
let toFilter;
if (a) {
  toFilter = false;
  return;
}

toFilter = b;
toFilter = c;
```

Let's say `a = false, b = true, c = false`, I assume you'd want `toFilter` to be `true`, as one of the conditions is true. What happens instead is that we see that `toFilter` is `false`.

To understand why, you can see that the code won't return, as the first condition is `false` and the `if` won't run. Then `toFilter` is set to `true` as the second condition is `true`, but then the previous value of `toFilter` is disregarded, and it's set to `false`.

To avoid this, one possibility is to make all the code look like the first case:

```
let toFilter;
if (a) {
  toFilter = false;
  return;
}

if (b) {
  toFilter = true;
  return;
}

if (c) {
  toFilter = true;
  return;
}
```

Now, there's clearly some duplicate code, but it will work.

We can use boolean operators to shorten it:

```
const toFilter = !a && (b || c);
```

It's important to note that boolean operators shortcircuit. For `x && y` this means that if `x` is `false`, then `y` won't even be evaluated. For `x || y`, if `x` is `true`, then `y` won't be evaluated, which means you aren't going to get errors or extra computations.

For you,

```
toFilter = this.filteredOut;
a = !cupFilters.intensities.length || !cupFilters.moments.length;
b = !cupFilters.intensities.includes(this.cup.intensity);
c = !cupFilters.moments.includes(this.cup. coffee_moment_id);
```

Noting that `!(!x || !y)` is the same as `x && y`, and `!x || !y` is the same as `!(x && y)`, your code can comfortably be

```
const { intensities, moments } = cupFilters;
this.filteredOut = (intensities.length && moments.length)
  && !(intensities.includes(this.cup.intensity) && moments.includes(this.cup.coffee_moment_id));
```

Feel free to rewrite this in whatever layout makes it more readable for you